# NGINX reverse proxy doesn't work with swagger-ui-express

Tags: nginx, node.js

I am using NGINX to `proxy_pass` all requests with prefix `/auth/` to a nodejs api server at `localhost:3000`.

I have this single config file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default3.conf`:

```
server {
    
    location /auth/ {
        rewrite /auth/(.+) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    }


}
```

It works fine for most of my requests (instead of GET `http://localhost:3000/logout`, GET `http://localhost/auth/logout` would work as expected), except this request GET `http://localhost/auth/docs`, which should map to `http://localhost:3000/docs` but I got a redirect:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 15 Dec 2021 01:59:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 175
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: /docs/
```

then a 404 NOT FOUND instead:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 15 Dec 2021 03:20:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

It seems like when I GET `http://localhost/auth/docs`, the request hit my nodejs server, but then got redirected back to `http://localhost/docs`, but how could this be possible? I still can GET `http://localhost:3000/docs` without a problem.

**UPDATED**

`http://localhost:3000/docs` is where I am serving Swagger UI for the server API, using the npm module `swagger-ui-express`.

Comment: Most probably your nodejs server is not configured with the correct base URL and generates the faulty redirects.

Comment: yes you're right. It was a problem with my nodejs app, i.e. the `swagger-ui-express` module. I'm still trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

- The problem lies in the module `swagger-ui-express` which my nodejs server is using to serve API docs.
- I configured it to serve on `/docs` and the module will make 301 redirects to make the request exactly `$HOST/docs`, for HOST is whatever the request host is (`localhost:3000`, or `localhost`).
- So, when put behind NGINX reverse proxy like I did, every GET `http://localhost/auth/docs` would hit my nodejs server but will be redirected to `http://localhost/docs` like I said in bullet point 2.

### The solution

- Configure NGINX to make another proxy_pass when the request match `/docs/`.

```
    location /docs/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/docs/;
    }
```

- **Be careful** that the URI being passed to has **a trailing slash**, because the module `swagger-ui-express` expects that trailing slash. Otherwise `/auth/docs` will be redirected to `/docs/` and `/docs/` will be redirected to `/auth/docs` again (infinite loop until error). Although it is okay to remove the trailing slash in both the location matching and the proxy pass URL.